# httr GET function running out of space when downloading a large file

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl, httr

i'm trying to download a file that's 1.1 gigabytes with `httr` but i'm hitting the following error:

```
x <- GET( extract.path )
Error in curlPerform(curl = handle$handle, .opts = curl_opts$values) : 
  cannot allocate more space: 1728053248 bytes
```

my C drive has 400GB free..

in the `RCurl` package, i see the `maxfilesize` and `maxfilesize.large` options when using `getCurlOptionsConstants()` but i don't understand if/how these might be passed to `httr` through `config` or `set_config`.. or if i need to switch over to `RCurl` for this..  and even if i do need to switch, will increasing the maximum filesize work?

here's my sessionInfo..

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] XML_3.96-1.1 httr_0.2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.0   RCurl_1.95-4.1 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.0
```

..and (*this is not recommended, just because it will take you a while*) if you want to reproduce my error, you can go to https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/samples, register for a new account, choose the 2011 5-year acs extract, add about a hundred variables, and then wait for the extract to be ready.  then edit the first three lines and run the code below.  (*again, not recommended*)

```
your.email <- "email@address.com"
your.password <- "password"
extract.path <- "https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/downloads/extract_files/some_file.csv.gz"

require(httr)

values <- 
    list(
        "login[email]" = your.email , 
        "login[password]" = your.password , 
        "login[is_for_login]" = 1
    )

POST( "https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/users/validate_login" , body = values )
GET( "https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/extract_requests/download" , query = values )

# this line breaks
x <- GET( extract.path )
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI - this has been added in the `write_disk()` control in `httr`:
https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/man/write_disk.Rd

Answer (score 1):

`GET` calls `httr:::make_request` this sets the curl options defined in `config = list()`. However it appears the `writefunction` otpion is hard coded in 'httr'

```
opts$writefunction <- getNativeSymbolInfo("R_curl_write_binary_data")$address
```

You will probably need to use RCurl and define an appropriate `writefunction'. The following 
solution [Create a C-level file handle in RCurl for writing downloaded files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456317/create-a-c-level-file-handle-in-rcurl-for-writing-downloaded-files/15463343#15463343) from @Martin Morgan appears to be the way to go.

Comment: thank you!  i think i am closer to the answer, but it's still not working.  i've moved all my code over from `httr` to `RCurl` and incorporated some of @Martin Morgan's answer, and since it's now very different, i've written [this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329288/how-to-download-a-large-binary-file-with-rcurl-after-server-authentication)..  i don't think there's a solution with `httr`?

Comment: Please file a bug - httr should be able to do this (although it won't be the default)