# how to download a large binary file with RCurl *after* server authentication

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl, httr

i originally asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306695/httr-get-function-running-out-of-space-when-downloading-a-large-file) about performing this task with the `httr` package, but i don't think it's possible using `httr`.  so i've re-written my code to use `RCurl` instead -- but i'm still tripping up on something probably related to the `writefunction`.. but i really don't understand why.

you should be able to reproduce my work by using the 32-bit version of R, so you hit memory limits if you read anything into RAM.  i need a solution that downloads directly to the hard disk.

to start, this code to *works* -- the zipped file is appropriately saved to the disk.

```
library(RCurl)
filename <- tempfile()
f <- CFILE(filename, "wb")
url <- "http://www2.census.gov/acs2011_5yr/pums/csv_pus.zip"
curlPerform(url = url, writedata = f@ref)
close(f)
# 2.1 GB file successfully written to disk
```

now here's some `RCurl` code that does not work.  as stated in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306695/httr-get-function-running-out-of-space-when-downloading-a-large-file), reproducing this exactly will require creating an extract on [ipums](http://www.ipums.org).

```
your.email <- "email@address.com"
your.password <- "password"
extract.path <- "https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/downloads/extract_files/some_file.csv.gz"

library(RCurl)

values <- 
    list(
        "login[email]" = your.email , 
        "login[password]" = your.password , 
        "login[is_for_login]" = 1
    )

curl = getCurlHandle()

curlSetOpt(
    cookiejar = 'cookies.txt', 
    followlocation = TRUE, 
    autoreferer = TRUE, 
    ssl.verifypeer = FALSE,
    curl = curl
)

params <- 
    list(
        "login[email]" = your.email , 
        "login[password]" = your.password , 
        "login[is_for_login]" = 1
    )

html <- postForm("https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/users/validate_login", .params = params, curl = curl)
dl <- getURL( "https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/extract_requests/download" , curl = curl)
```

and now that i'm logged in, try the same commands as above, but with the `curl` object to keep the cookies.

```
filename <- tempfile()
f <- CFILE(filename, mode = "wb")
```

this line breaks--

```
curlPerform(url = extract.path, writedata = f@ref, curl = curl)
close(f)

# the error is:
Error in curlPerform(url = extract.path, writedata = f@ref, curl = curl) : 
  embedded nul in string: [[binary jibberish here]]
```

the answer to my previous post referred me to [this c-level writefunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456317/create-a-c-level-file-handle-in-rcurl-for-writing-downloaded-files/15463343#15463343) answer, but i'm clueless about how to re-create that curl_writer C program (on windows?)..

```
dyn.load("curl_writer.so")
writer <- getNativeSymbolInfo("writer", PACKAGE="curl_writer")$address
curlPerform(URL=url, writefunction=writer)
```

..or why it's even necessary, given that the five lines of code at the top of this question work without anything crazy like `getNativeSymbolInfo`.  i just don't understand why passing in that extra `curl` object that stores the authentication/cookies and tells it not to verify SSL would cause code that otherwise works.. to break?

Comment: What happens if you edit the code that works adding `curl = getCurlHandle()` and `curlPerform(url = url, writedata = f@ref, curl = curl)`? and, are you able to download some other content once session has started? for example, using `curlPerform` and `writedata` to save `https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/extract_requests/download`

Comment: About the C code, you'd need to compile it into a DLL, and then `dyn.load("curl_writer.dll")`

Comment: 1) i don't understand how your editing getCurlHandle() is any different from my code?  2) yes, i am able to download other content once the session has started.  `z <- getBinaryURL( extract.path , curl = curl )` works, but it reads everything into RAM and so doesn't solve my problem.  3) is it possible to do this within R on windows?  thanks!! :)

Comment: Compile the code using Visual C++ or cigwin, or check this page: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/SHLIB.html

Comment: @AstDerek any chance i could convince you to provide a working example start-to-finish? :)  this non-R stuff is unintelligible to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is now possible with the `httr` package.  thanks hadley!

https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/44

Answer (score 3):

1. From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456317/create-a-c-level-file-handle-in-rcurl-for-writing-downloaded-files/15463343#15463343) create a file named `curl_writer.c` and save it to `C:\<folder where you save your R files>`

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   /**
    * Original code just sent some message to stderr
    */
   size_t writer(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) {
       fwrite(buffer,size,nmemb,(FILE *)stream);
       return size * nmemb;
   }
   ```
2. Open a command window, go to the folder where you saved `curl_writer.c` and run the R compiler

   ```
   c:> cd "C:\<folder where you save your R files>"
   c:> R CMD SHLIB -o curl_writer.dll curl_writer.c
   ```
3. Open R and run your script

   ```
   C:> R

   your.email <- "email@address.com"
   your.password <- "password"
   extract.path <- "https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/downloads/extract_files/some_file.csv.gz"

   library(RCurl)

   values <- 
       list(
           "login[email]" = your.email , 
           "login[password]" = your.password , 
           "login[is_for_login]" = 1
       )

   curl = getCurlHandle()

   curlSetOpt(
       cookiejar = 'cookies.txt', 
       followlocation = TRUE, 
       autoreferer = TRUE, 
       ssl.verifypeer = FALSE,
       curl = curl
   )

   params <- 
       list(
           "login[email]" = your.email , 
           "login[password]" = your.password , 
           "login[is_for_login]" = 1
       )

   html <- postForm("https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/users/validate_login", .params = params, curl = curl)
   dl <- getURL( "https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/extract_requests/download" , curl = curl)

   # Load the DLL you created
   # "writer" is the name of the function
   # "curl_writer" is the name of the dll
   dyn.load("curl_writer.dll")
   writer <- getNativeSymbolInfo("writer", PACKAGE="curl_writer")$address

   # Note that "URL" parameter is upper case, in your code it is lowercase
   # I'm not sure if that has something to do
   # "writer" is the symbol defined above
   f <- CFILE(filename <- tempfile(), "wb")
   curlPerform(URL=url, writedata=f@ref, writefunction=writer, curl=curl)
   close(f)
   ```

Comment: thanks!!  ..but when i run this in windows - `setwd( "C:/My Directory" ) ; cwr <- "#include <stdio.h>\n\nsize_t writer(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) {\nfwrite(buffer,size,nmemb,(FILE *)stream);\nreturn size * nmemb;\n}" ; writeLines( cwr , "curl_writer.c" ) ; shell( "'C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.0\\bin\\x64\\Rcmd.exe' SHLIB -o 'C:\\My Directory\\curl_writer.dll' 'C:\\My Directory\\curl_writer.c'" )` - i get `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.[[snip]]execution failed with error code 1`  any idea what's wrong? i want to keep it within R :)

Comment: `system2(command="R",args="CMD SHLIB -o curl_writer.dll curl_writer.c")` instead of `shell(...)`

Comment: thank you again, and sorry if i'm missing something obvious here.. `R` isn't in my PATH, so i used `system2( command = "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.0\\bin\\x64\\R.exe" , args = "CMD SHLIB -o curl_writer.dll curl_writer.c" )` but that gave a warning `running command '"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.0\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD SHLIB -o curl_writer.dll curl_writer.c' had status 1` and didn't create the `.dll` file..  :/

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, I'm using a Mac and it works with no problem here. Maybe you need to install a compiler or something? Can you ask somebody else to compile the DLL for you?

Comment: This solution requires a compiler to be installed. That's usually the case on linux and mac, but not on windows. So you will probably need to manually install a C compiler (and maybe tell R where to find it).