# how to authenticate a shibboleth multi-hostname website with httr in R

Tags: r, post, shibboleth, httr

note: ipums international and ipums usa probably use the same system.  ipums usa allows quicker signup.  if you would like to test out your code, try https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/users/request_access to sign up!

i am trying to programmatically download a file from https://international.ipums.org/ with the R language and httr.  i need to use httr and not RCurl because i need to post-authentication download large files *not* into RAM but directly to disk.  [this is currently only possible with `httr` as far as i know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329288/how-to-download-a-large-binary-file-with-rcurl-after-server-authentication)

the reproducible code below documents my best effort at getting from the login page (https://international.ipums.org/international-action/users/login) to the main post-authentication page.  any tips or hints would be appreciated!  thanks!

```
my_email <- "email@address.com"
my_password <- "password"

tf <- tempfile()

# use httr, because i need to download a large file after authentication
# and only httr supports that with its `write_disk()` option
library(httr)

# turn off ssl verify, otherwise the subsequent GET command will fail
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )

GET( "https://international.ipums.org/Shibboleth.sso/Login?target=https%3A%2F%2Finternational.ipums.org%2Finternational-action%2Fmenu" )

# connect to the starting login page of the website
( a <- GET( "https://international.ipums.org/international-action/users/login" , verbose( info = TRUE ) ) )

# which takes me through to a lot of websites, but ultimately (in my browser) lands at
shibboleth_url <- "https://live.identity.popdata.org:443/idp/Authn/UserPassword"

# construct authentication information?
base_values <- list( "j_username" = my_email , "j_password" = my_password )
idp_values <- list( "j_username" = my_email , "j_password" = my_password ,  "_idp_authn_lc_key"=subset( a$cookies , domain == "live.identity.popdata.org" )$value , "JSESSIONID" = subset( a$cookies , domain == "#HttpOnly_live.identity.popdata.org" )$value )
ipums_values <- list( "j_username" = my_email , "j_password" = my_password ,  "_idp_authn_lc_key"=subset( a$cookies , domain == "live.identity.popdata.org" )$value , "JSESSIONID" = subset( a$cookies , domain == "international.ipums.org" )$value)

# i believe this is where the main login should happen, but it looks like it's failing
GET( shibboleth_url , query = idp_values )
POST( shibboleth_url , body = base_values )
writeBin( GET( shibboleth_url , query = idp_values )$content , tf )

readLines( tf )
# The MPC account authentication system has encountered an error
# This error can sometimes occur if you did not close your browser after logging out of an application previously.  It may also occur for other reasons.  Please close your browser and try your action again."                                                                      

writeBin( GET( "https://live.identity.popdata.org/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO" , query = idp_values )$content , tf )
POST( "https://live.identity.popdata.org/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO" , body = idp_values )
readLines( tf )
# same error as above

# return to the main login page..
writeBin( GET( "https://international.ipums.org/international-action/menu" , query = ipums_values )$content , tf )
readLines( tf )
# ..not logged in
```

Comment: Have you thought about RSelenium for this?

Comment: @Thomas hi, i would not know where to start.  i would be open to it, so long as it can download an arbitrarily large file _post-authentication_ (which `httr` can but `RCurl` cannot)

Comment: not so much to try without actually having an account there :(

Comment: @cyberj0g see edit at top, you should be able to get an account easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `set_cookies()` to send your cookies to the server:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
#my_email <- "xxx"
#my_password <- "yyy"
tf <- tempfile()
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )

# Get first page
p1 <- GET( "https://international.ipums.org/international-action/users/login" , verbose( info = TRUE ) )

# Post Login credentials
b2 <- list( "j_username" = my_email , "j_password" = my_password )
c2 <- c(JSESSIONID=p1$cookies[p1$cookies$domain=="#HttpOnly_live.identity.popdata.org",]$value,
           `_idp_authn_lc_key`=p1$cookies[p1$cookies$domain=="live.identity.popdata.org",]$value)
p2 <- POST(p1$url,body = b2, set_cookies(.cookies = c2), encode="form" )

# Parse hidden fields
h2 <- read_html(p2$content)
form <-  h2 %>% html_form() 

# Post hidden fields
b3 <- list( "RelayState"=form[[1]]$fields[[1]]$value, "SAMLResponse"=form[[1]]$fields[[2]]$value)
c3 <- c(JSESSIONID=p1$cookies[p1$cookies$domain=="#HttpOnly_live.identity.popdata.org",]$value,
           `_idp_session`=p2$cookies[p2$cookies$name=="_idp_session",]$value,
           `_idp_authn_lc_key`=p2$cookies[p2$cookies$name=="_idp_authn_lc_key",]$value)
p3 <- POST( form[[1]]$url , body=b3, set_cookies(.cookies = c3), encode = "form")

# Get interesting page
c4 <- c(JSESSIONID=p3$cookies[p1$cookies$domain=="international.ipums.org" && p3$cookies$name=="JSESSIONID",]$value,
           `_idp_session`=p3$cookies[p3$cookies$name=="_idp_session",]$value,
           `_idp_authn_lc_key`=p3$cookies[p3$cookies$name=="_idp_authn_lc_key",]$value)
p4 <- GET( "https://international.ipums.org/international-action/menu", set_cookies(.cookies = c4) )
writeBin(p4$content , tf )
readLines( tf )[55]
```

Since the result is

```
[1] "    <li class=\"lastItem\"><a href=\"/international-action/users/logout\">Logout</a></li>"
```

I think you're logged in...

Comment: perfect.  thanks.  credited here https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/commit/79988d577b98b250a17e606630153b8e67698c2e

Answer (score 2):

@HubertL have done many steps in the right direction, however, I think, his answer is not complete.

First of all, the main thing to look at when you're implementing automatic web authorization is the cookies being used during 'normal' manual workflow. You can easily spy on them with dev tools in any modern browser:
[image]

Here, we see `JSESSIONID` and `_shibsession*` cookies, first one holds JSP session id of the website, second is most likely solely for a shibboleth authorization. Server is, probably, have them bound somehow, but `JSESSIONID` doesn't require authorization and you get it right away after opening the website. So, we must get `_shibsession*` cookie for our `JSESSIONID` to be authorized. That's what the Shibboleth's authorization process with many redirects is about. See the comments in code.

```
login_ipums = function(user, password)
{
  require(httr)
  require(rvest)

  set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )

  #important - httr preserves cookies on subsequent requests to the same host, we don't need that because of sessions expiration
  handle_reset("https://usa.ipums.org/")

  #set login and password
  login1 = GET( "https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/users/login" )
  form_auth = list( "j_username" = user , "j_password" = password )

  l1_cookies=login1$cookies$value
  names(l1_cookies)=login1$cookies$name

  #receive auth tokens as html hidden fields in a form
  login2 = POST(login1$url, body = form_auth, set_cookies(.cookies=l1_cookies), encode="form")
  login2_form = read_html(login2$content) %>% html_form() 

  l2_cookies=login2$cookies$value
  names(l2_cookies)=login2$cookies$name

  #submit the form back (browser submits it back automatically with JS)
  login3 = POST(login2_form[[1]]$url, body=list(RelayState=login2_form[[1]]$fields$RelayState$value, 
                                                SAMLResponse=login2_form[[1]]$fields$SAMLResponse$value), 
                set_cookies(.cookies=l2_cookies), 
                encode="form")

  #now we have what we came for - _shibsession_* and JSESSION id cookie
  login_cookies = login3$cookies$value
  names(login_cookies)=login3$cookies$name

  return=login_cookies
}
```

After the call to `login_ipums` we'll have the following cookies:

```
> cookies=login_ipums(my_email, my_password)
> names(cookies)
[1] "JSESSIONID"      
[2] "_idp_authn_lc_key"             
[3] "_shibsession_7573612e69..."
```

Here, we have both `JSESSIONID` and `_shibsession_*` used for site-wide authorization. `_idp_authn_lc_key` is, probably, not needed, but leaving it won't hurt.

Now, you can easily download files like that:

```
cookies=login_ipums(my_email, my_password)
target = GET("https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/downloads/extract_files/usa_00001.dat.gz",
         set_cookies(.cookies=cookies),
         write_disk("file.bin", overwrite = TRUE))
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: As you can see, I used IPUMS USA, not International. To check that code with your account, replace `usa` with `international` everywhere, including `*-action` in URLs.

Comment: amazing, thanks!  @HubertL's code does work for me, looks like yours does as well.  thank you!!

Comment: Ok, but note that @HubertL's code never sets `_shibsession_*` (actual authorization token) cookie explicitly, it (possibly unintentionally) relies on `httr` cookie persistence mechanism and that may be an issue on production.