# How to set the domain of cookies in R using rvest, httr, curl?

Tags: curl, session-cookies, rcurl, rvest, httr

How can one set the domains for cookies in R using the rvest/httr/curl packages?

I know that one typically sets cookies using a named character vector of names and values (as `?set_cookies` reports).  Is it possible to specify the domains as well?  Or, maybe better yet, to send the whole seven-column Netscape spec that one gets back from `httr::cookies()`?

The problem arises because I'm trying to automate the shibboleth-based login process for the [UK Data Service](https://www.ukdataservice.ac.uk/), which uses a complex set of session cookies (see my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701409/r-use-rvest-or-httr-to-log-in-to-a-site-requiring-cookies)).  In the final step of the login process, the site passes two cookies with the same name (`JSESSIONID`) but for different domains (`#HttpOnly_wayf.ukfederation.org.uk` and `shib.data-archive.ac.uk`).  As just a named vector, though, the two `JSESSIONID`s look alike.  I've tried passing back just one or the other, but perhaps not surprisingly it seems that both are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the argument `config = config(cookiejar = 'cookies.txt')` to your `rvest` command, e.g., `submit_form(session = s, form = f, config = config(cookiejar = 'cookies.txt'))`, does the trick.  There's no need to have previously generated a file named cookies.txt, btw: it's all done automagically.